# Display alert after conditions are met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help with modifying the code below. I would like it to display an alert only when two conditions are met.

1. all cells in the table have been applied a background color
2. number of Red cells equal number of Yellow cells - Completed

The code below meets the 2nd requirement and I need help on the 1st requirement

```js
jQuery(function() {

  var brush = "white_block";

  jQuery('input.block').on('click', function() {
    brush = jQuery(this).data('brush');
  });

  jQuery('td').on('click',function() {

    jQuery(this).removeClass('white_block yellow_block red_block').addClass(brush);

    var reds = jQuery('.red_block').length,
        yellows = jQuery('.yellow_block').length;

    if (reds == yellows) {
      setTimeout(function() {alert("Finished!")}, 100);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.block {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
}
.white_block {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.red_block {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
.yellow_block {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

table {
  margin:1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="block white_block" data-brush="white_block">
<input type="button" class="block yellow_block" data-brush="yellow_block">
<input type="button" class="block red_block" data-brush="red_block">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your question : how to trigger event when all cells of the table have a color class (.red_block or .yellow_block ) ?

Comment: Why timeout ? why Jquery instead of $ ?

Comment: @singebatteur usually `jQuery` instead of `$` is best to avoid any conflicting library issues which may also use the `$` variable.

Comment: So all the libraries editor ignore that 90% use $ ?

Comment: @singebatteur no, most are aware of this but it's rare that you will need to use many libraries for a single project so it's not that big of a deal.

Comment: yep, but you are actually right on the conflicting side !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom function to check your conditions and call it each item a cell is clicked.

The function will check for total cells, how many are colored and if the reds equal yellows:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var brush = "white_block";
  jQuery('input.block').on('click', function() {
    brush = jQuery(this).data('brush');
  });
  function cellCheck() {
    var reds = jQuery('#cellsTable .red_block').length,
        yellows = jQuery('#cellsTable .yellow_block').length,
        cells_colored = reds + yellows,
        cells_total = jQuery('#cellsTable td').length;
    
    // condition 1: all colored 
    if (cells_colored == cells_total) {
      setTimeout(function() {alert("All Colored");}, 100);
    }
    // condition 2: equal colors
    if (reds == yellows) {
      setTimeout(function() {alert("Equal colors");}, 100);
    }
    // condition 3: both conditions
    if (cells_colored == cells_total && reds == yellows) {
      setTimeout(function() {alert("Finished!");}, 100);
    }
  }
  jQuery('td').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('white_block yellow_block red_block').addClass(brush);
    cellCheck();
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
}
.white_block {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.red_block {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
.yellow_block {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
table {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="block white_block" data-brush="white_block">
<input type="button" class="block yellow_block" data-brush="yellow_block">
<input type="button" class="block red_block" data-brush="red_block">

<table id="cellsTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count all `td` with class `block` and all `td` with class `red_block` or `yellow_block` and then compare them like following.

```
var brush = "white_block";

$('input.block').on('click', function () {
    brush = $(this).data('brush');
});

$('td').on('click', function () {

    $(this).removeClass('white_block yellow_block red_block').addClass(brush);

    var all = $('td.block').length,
      colored = $('td.red_block, td.yellow_block').length,
      reds = $('td.red_block').length,
      yellows = $('td.yellow_block').length;

    if (reds == yellows && all == colored) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert("Finished!")
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fn2b8Lgh/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

`reds = jQuery('.red_block').length` & `yellows= jQuery('.yellow_block').length` will find every elements with classes `red_block` & `yellow_block` other than. I changed this to `reds = jQuery('td.red_block').length` & `yellows= jQuery('td.yellow_block').length` respective to find only `td`s.

1.Find total of  `td.red_block` => `reds` & `td.yellow_block`=>`yellows`.

2.Calculate total of `reds` & `yellows` => `totalbg`.

3.Find total of all `td` with class `.block` => `totaltd`;

4.If `reds==yellows` And `totalbg==totaltd` then show `alert()`

```js
jQuery(function() {

  var brush = "white_block";

  jQuery('input.block').on('click', function() {
    brush = jQuery(this).data('brush');
  });

  jQuery('td').on('click',function() {

    jQuery(this).removeClass('white_block yellow_block red_block').addClass(brush);

    var reds = jQuery('td.red_block').length,
        yellows = jQuery('td.yellow_block').length,
        totaltd=$('td.block').length,
        totalbg = reds + yellows;
        

    if (reds == yellows && totalbg==totaltd) {
      setTimeout(function() {alert("Finished!")}, 100);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.block {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
}
.white_block {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.red_block {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
.yellow_block {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

table {
  margin:1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="block white_block" data-brush="white_block">
<input type="button" class="block yellow_block" data-brush="yellow_block">
<input type="button" class="block red_block" data-brush="red_block">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
    <td class="block red_block"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```